# Groovy script header response parsing

Tags: groovy

I would need to parse a POST call header to obtain the id  from a location URL using groovy script and used the format from another post but get an error message

```
def url = ('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.com/test_link/locatedat/125114');
def strArray = url.tokenize('/');
def fetchId = strArray.last();
log.info fetchId;
```

Error message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.tokenize() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/] Possible solutions: takeWhile(groovy.lang.Closure), takeWhile(groovy.lang.Closure) error at line: 3
```

Comment: Can you post your actual code? The code above can't cause the error you claim

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to get the last bit of a URL path? Or do you mean the headers of the post as you say in the title?